# How do I use MediatR with Autofac in ASP MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, mediatr

The author provides an [example](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR.Examples.Autofac/Program.cs) of how to use [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) in a console application using Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (IMediator).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (Ping).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterInstance(Console.Out).As<TextWriter>();

var lazy = new Lazy<IServiceLocator>(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(builder.Build()));
var serviceLocatorProvider = new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => lazy.Value);
builder.RegisterInstance(serviceLocatorProvider);
```

I took this example and *attempted* to make it work with ASP MVC 5 and the [Autofac.Mvc5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5/) package:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AddPostCommand).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
var container = builder.Build();
var lazy = new Lazy<IServiceLocator>(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(container));
var serviceLocatorProvider = new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => lazy.Value);
builder.RegisterInstance(serviceLocatorProvider);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

When I run the web application, I get an error page telling me that the `ServiceLocationProvider` dependency has not been registered. What am I doing wrong?

I *suspect* that the problem is due to the fact that I am registering the `ServiceLocatorProvider` instance *after* calling `Build` - in the author's example, the `Build` method is invoked afterwards thanks to `Lazy<>`. I do not know how to work around this, though.

Answer (score 3):

I had issues to properly register both the `Mediator` and `ServiceLocatorProvider` classes.
I pulled my hair for a while, but finally managed to get around it.

My mistake was to register `ServiceLocatorProvider` against the root Autofac container, like this:

```cs
var lazyContainer = new Lazy<IContainer>(() => builder.Build());
builder.Register(x => new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLoator(lazyContainer.Value)));

DependencyResolver.SetCurrent(new AutofacDependencyResolver(lazyContainer.Value);
```

At runtime, Autofac was throwing an exception because one of my `Request` had a dependency on my EF `DbContext` that I configured to be scoped by HTTP request.

The trick is to register the `ServiceLocatorProvider` against the current HTTP request `ILifetimeScope`.
Thankfully, the error message from Autofac is self explanatory:

```
No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being
requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration
always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime,
never from the container itself.
```

This happens because the `AutofacServiceLocator` was fed with the root container.
The container, when asking to resolve the `DbContext`, has no knowledge of an inner - associated with to the current HTTP request - scope.

Using JustDecompile, I sax that the only class implementing the `ILifetimeScopeProvider` interface was `AutofacDependencyResolver`, and you can access the current instance with the static property `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current`.

You can access the current `ILifetimeScope` by using `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope` as explained in the error message, so in the end the registration looks like:

```cs
builder
    .Register(x => new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope)))
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

The `InstancePerHttpRequest()` part is optional but since the `ILifetimeScope` will be the same during the whole HTTP request, this prevents Autofac from creating n instances of `AutofacServiceLocator`.

Hope this was clear, don't hesitate to make some edits if you feel like it's necessary, because I have a hard time explaining this clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Webapi 2 + Autofac + OWIN and manage to get it working. Here is my code:

Here is my autofac Constructor

```
        //Constructor
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces(); 
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        // Register Web API controller in executing assembly.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();


        var lazyContainer = new Lazy<IContainer>(() => builder.Build());
        var serviceLocatorProvider = new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(lazyContainer.Value));
        builder.RegisterInstance(serviceLocatorProvider);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(lazyContainer.Value);


        // This should be the first middleware added to the IAppBuilder.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(lazyContainer.Value);

        // Make sure the Autofac lifetime scope is passed to Web API.
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
```

Here are my namespaces:

```
using System; 
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using Autofac;
using CommonServiceLocator.AutofacAdapter.Unofficial;
using Autofac.Features.Variance;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using Owin;
```

Everything worked fine and did not had to explict register every requestHandler or CommandHandler. Since I also lost a LOT of time to put it togueter I do hope that it will help others having the same issue. Past answers were helpfull to get to this one.

**UPDATE:**

Well, I just refactor de code to remove all the lazy binding making it much simpler. Bellow are the changes:

Instead of:

```
        var lazyContainer = new Lazy<IContainer>(() => builder.Build());
        var serviceLocatorProvider = new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(lazyContainer.Value));
        builder.RegisterInstance(serviceLocatorProvider);
```

Just use :

```
        builder.RegisterType<AutofacServiceLocator>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
        var container = builder.Build();

        //ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(serviceLocatorProvider);            
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Builder.Build before you finish registering types.

in your example you are calling Builder.Build before you call builder.RegisterInstance which explains why it cannot infer the type at runtime.

I came up with this after hitting the same issue today, but it is work in progress as it doesnt resolve my implementations yet...

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(HomePageThumbnail).Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var lifetimeScope = new Lazy<ILifetimeScope>(() => builder.Build());
        var lazy = new Lazy<IServiceLocator>(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(lifetimeScope.Value));

        var serviceLocatorProvider = new ServiceLocatorProvider(() => lazy.Value);
        builder.RegisterInstance(serviceLocatorProvider);


        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(lifetimeScope.Value));

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(lifetimeScope.Value);
        app.UseAutofacMvc();
```

I am creating the container in a separate `Lazy<T>` and passing that around.

While this builds and the site loads, it cannot infer which handler to use for the request in my controller action...

```
var response = _mediator.Send(new RecentActivityThumbnailsQuery());
```

which raises the exception...

```
    An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Activation error occurred while trying to get instance of type IRequestHandler`2, key ""
```

This is using the same convention based registration provided in the Autofac examples project included in MediatR, and i have also tried registering it explicitly....

```
builder.RegisterType<RecentActivityThumbnailsHandler>().As<IRequestHandler<RecentActivityThumbnailsQuery, RecentActivityThumbnailsResults>>();
```

I will update when i get it working.  Please do the same if you figure it out before i do.